# lib/pass_server_ctl -s failed

Tags: ruby, xamarin, server, wallet

I am trying to setup an Apple Wallet Pass server. I downloaded WalletCompanionFiles from Apple developper site. I have xcode 9.3.1 and I have xcode command line tools installed.

I did the following command :

```
$ sudo gem install sinatra sequel sqlite3 rubyzip rack yaml json terminal-table
```

Most of it succeded except I have the following error :

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'yaml' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: zaml, cyaml, faml, haml, maml
```

Then I entered the next command, but it failed and I am not sure how to fix this :

```
$ lib/pass_server_ctl -s
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:225:in `open_loop': redirection forbidden: http://jsonip.com -> https://jsonip.com/ (RuntimeError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:151:in `open_uri'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:717:in `open'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:35:in `open'
    from lib/pass_server_ctl:30:in `setup_hostname'
    from lib/pass_server_ctl:228:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

The `yaml` library is part of the Ruby standard library, so you should not need to install that from Ruby Gems.

Looks like the jsonip.com service is now redirecting to HTTPS URLs. I don't have access to the WalletCompanionFiles code, but my guess is that somewhere in `lib/pass_server_ctl` it references that URL but uses the HTTP protocol.

You should be able to replace that URL with `https://jsonip.com/` and get past the open-uri error.

*tl;dr*: Just add an `s` to `http` on line 30 of `lib/pass_server_ctl`